# tupla fuera de rango python

Tags: python, flask, tuplas

estoy creando un crud en python con flask y flask-mysqldb, ademas de procedimientos almacenados.
lo que sucede es que al momento de querer almacenar los datos me aparece un error el cual dice indice de tupla fuera de rango en que podría estar fallando?

tengo un archivo usuarios.py en una carpeta llamada entidades el cual tiene los siguientes datos

```
class Usuarios(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id, usuario_Usuarios, clave_Usuarios, nombre_Usuarios = "", id_Rol_Usuarios = "", estado_Usuarios = "", fecha_Usuarios = "") -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.usuario_Usuarios = usuario_Usuarios
        self.clave_Usuarios = clave_Usuarios
        self.nombre_Usuarios = nombre_Usuarios
        self.id_Rol_Usuarios = id_Rol_Usuarios
        self.estado_Usuarios = estado_Usuarios
        self.fecha_Usuarios = fecha_Usuarios
```

luego tengo otro archivo llamado consultasUsuarios.py guardado en una carpeta consultas que tiene los siguientes datos.

```
@classmethod
cur = db.connection.cursor()
            query_sql = "CALL sp_Usuarios_Listar()"
            cur.execute(query_sql)
            row = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            if row != None:
                user = Usuarios(row[0], row[1], None, row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

al momento de llamar a todo estos procedimientos en app.py me dice que el incide esta fuera de rango, este es el código de app.py

```
#Decorador para editar usuarios
@app.route('/edit_user')
@login_required
def edit_user():
    roll = session["id_Rol_Usuarios"]
    if roll == "1":
        lista_user = consultaUsuarios.Usuarios_Listar(db)
        return render_template('admin/edit_user.html', users = lista_user)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('logout'))
```

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar en una tabla de bootstras 5 todas las filas de mi tabla usuarios. le estará faltando algo?

segun el error que me lanza el error se encuentra en esta linea

```
user = Usuarios(row[0], row[1], None, row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
```

comando de sql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Usuarios_Listar ()
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        id, 
        usuario_Usuarios, 
        nombre_Usuarios, 
        id_Rol_Usuarios, 
        Estado_Usuarios, 
        fecha_Usuarios 
    FROM 
        usuarios;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Imprime el valor de `row` y edita tu pregunta añadiendo el resultado

Answer (score 1):

Solución

la solución fue cambiar el código por el siguiente

```
@classmethod
    def Usuarios_Listar(self, db):
        try:
            cur = db.connection.cursor()
            query_sql = "CALL sp_Usuarios_Listar()"
            cur.execute(query_sql)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            
            if data != None:
                user = []
                for row in data:
                    usuario = Usuarios(row[0], row[1], None, row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
                    user.append(usuario)
                    
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

ahora el llamado a las filas en html se hace de la siguiente manera

```
{% for user in users %}
       <tr>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.usuario_Usuarios }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.nombre_Usuarios }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.id_Rol_Usuarios }}</td>
```

esto fue lo que me funciono a mi

lo otro tambien puede ser usar el siguiente código

```
@classmethod
    def Usuarios_Listar(self, db):
        try:
            cur = db.connection.cursor()
            query_sql = "CALL sp_Usuarios_Listar()"
            cur.execute(query_sql)
            row = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            if row != None:
                return row
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

y en html se llamaria asi

```
{% for user in users %}
       <tr>
            <td>{{ user.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.3 }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema pudiera estar en la línea del `fetchall()`, ya que esta instrucción siempre traerá una lista bidimensional que sirve para ser recorrida en un ciclo. Ver [Esta Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189997/1545868)

Suponiendo tienes una tabla con los siguientes datos:

```
id | Nombre | apellido
-- + ------ + --------
2  | Juan   | Perez
5  | Marta  | Rodriguez
```

El resultado de `fetchall()` a hacerle un `SELECT` a toda la tabla será:

```py
> row = cur.fetchall()
> print(row)
[(2, 'Juan', 'Perez'), (5, 'Marta', 'Rodriguez')] # <--
>
> print(row[0])
(2, 'Juan', 'Perez')
>
> print(row[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
>
> print(row[0][2])
Perez
```

Si quieres solo el primer resultado, también podrías usar `fetchone()`, y esto debería arreglar tu código:

```py
> row = cur.fetchone()
> print(row)
(2, 'Juan', 'Perez')
>
> print(row[2])
Perez
```